# Hash/Revision CSS Output from Stylus

Tags: node.js, stylus

I would like to automatically append the hash/revision of the CSS bundle Stylus generates to the file name and create some kind of manifest file that stores the information. I want to use that output file to update my HTML with the resultant hashed file name for the CSS. Is there a way to do this *without* using Gulp or Grunt or any other task runner?

Comment: How are you outputting the css and how are you using that css file in your html?

Comment: `stylus style/main.styl -o public/styles.css` and just a regular `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles.css">`. I'm planning on switching to Jade and exposing this manifest file to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I think you are in [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/) territory with what you want to do. You might want to look into [CSS Modules](http://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules) also.